# Jquery slider movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm working on a project and i have to change the slider movement but i am not sure to how to change the movement direction.Right now it's moving from right to left but i want movement from up to down.Here is link of project on which i am working http://184.173.9.8/~intellis/isg/ the slider is located under Partner heading on right side.

Comment: You are much better off posting relavent code than asking everyone to weed through everything to find the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/  you can also use the css http://api.jquery.com/css/ function to specify where does the animation start and use jQuery animate to put the final position http://api.jquery.com/animate/. With the first function you should be able to resolve your problem with the second one you can create your own animations. Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 1):

1- you should change the height attribute of `ul` like this.

```
<ul id="home-widget-slider" style="height: 300px; width: 500px; left: -1000px; " class="anythingBase"><li class="cloned panel" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; "></ul>
```

2- You should hide the all `li` except first

```
$(function(){
 var i = 0;
  $("li").each(function(){
     if(i++>0)
       $(this).hide();
  })
})
```

3- i couldnt see the javascript but you should do this for `li`

```
$("#home-widget-slider li activePage").removeClass("activePage").slideUp(400).next().addClass("activePage").slideDown(300);
```